# What is D option in linux yum assisted install?

Tags: yum, installation, options

When I install something with yum installer on linux, I get something like this:

Is this ok [y/d/N]: _

So... what is the "D" option?

Comment: Read `man yum`.

Comment: I forgot that, 'cause I am not spending a lot of time on linux.
Anyway, you could just answer if you knew...

Comment: You already had the answer. My comment was meant to remember you that this exist and should be the first step to solve such a mystery.

Comment: My only step was google search, and I just couldn't find what I need. So I figure, if someone else would need the same thing here is where it will be indexed for sure.

Comment: @MladenJanjetovic It worked. Posting your question and the answer below helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stand for download only. Same as

```
yum --downloadonly
```